# Microsoft Graph Client - Promise - Return value to next .then() is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm struggeling with returning the result of a Promise to the next `.then` function.
I'm sure I'm blind and it is really small issue, but actually I can't see the reason why in the parameter of the next `.then` function is always `undefined`.

This is my Promise:

```
await this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory
  .getClient('3')
  .then(async (client: MSGraphClientV3) => {
    return await client
      .api(`/groups/{${this.state.group?.id}}/members`)
      .version("v1.0")
      .get(async (err, res) => {

        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }

        return res.value;
      });
    })
    .then(async (users: Array<MicrosoftGraph.User>) => {
      //users is always undefined
      ...
```

See the screenshots of debugging:

`res.value` is set correctly:

[image]

...but in next `.then` function the parameter is undefined:

[image]

Can anybody please tell me, what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot reproduce `users` being `undefined` using a simplified version of the code you provided.

Comment: You are returning from a `.get()` callback, not from a promise `.then()` callback. Avoid either, use only `async`/`await` when you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning from a `.get(…)` callback, not from a promise `.then()` callback. The [client `get` method](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/docs/CallingPattern.md#callback-based-calling) appears not to return a promise when you pass a callback, and it certainly doesn't return a promise for the result of the callback. You want to use the [promise API](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/docs/CallingPattern.md#promise-based-calling) instead where `.get()` (when you don't pass a callback) returns a promise, which you can chain `.then()` or `await`.

In general, don't pass `async` functions as callbacks, and avoid using `.then()` when you can easily `await` instead. Your code then becomes

```
const client: MSGraphClientV3 = await this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient('3');

const res = await client
  .api(`/groups/{${this.state.group?.id}}/members`)
  .version("v1.0")
  .get();

const users: Array<MicrosoftGraph.User> = res.value;
…
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with casting in typescript, but the endpoint `GET /groups/{groupId}/members` returns by default a collection of `directoryObject`s.

`user` derives from `directoryObject` and in `then` method you expect a collection of `user`s and maybe casting is not performed.

I would expect that

```
.then(async (members: Array<MicrosoftGraph.DirectoryObject>) => {...}
```

should work, and then try cast `directoryObject` to `user` in the method.

Or if you want to really retrieve users, you can perform server casting

```
await this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory
  .getClient('3')
  .then(async (client: MSGraphClientV3) => {
    return await client
      .api(`/groups/{${this.state.group?.id}}/members/microsoft.graph.user`)
      .version("v1.0")
      .get(async (err, res) => {

        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }

        return res.value;
      });
    })
    .then(async (users: Array<MicrosoftGraph.User>) => {..}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters

Comment: I'm sorry, both does not work. I've tried with `directoryObject` and the cast to `microsoft.graph.user`. Both gave the same result as before.

Comment: Casting in typescript is (mostly) just type hint suggestions for the compiler.  They shouldn't have any bearing on shuffling this data around.